# How to deploy asp.net core api application to azure

Tags: c#

I tried much time my project deploy successful but when I check my URL its return JSON data. I want to access my API and project data

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(options =>
                    options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader());

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CameraApp v1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you clarify what you need help with?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.